# [object object], [object object] showing after loading data from json placeholder api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, jsonplaceholder

I am using react v18.1.0 
I am trying to load users data from Json Placeholder API. After loading the data, I am setting it in a state called 'users'. After console.log(users), it show an Array of 10 objects. That's fine.
**But after 3/4 milliseconds it show [object object], [object object], [object object].**
why it Happens? Can anyone describe it, please.
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCXHn.png)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Users = () => {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setUsers(data))
    }, [])
    console.log(users);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{users.length}</h1>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because console.log(users) is getting executed every time the  component getting re-rendered.

You have to wrap it inside useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(users)
},[users]);
```

this will cause the console log to execute everytime the users state changes.